# Get fields from a nested json url

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the fields(python 3):

1. traffictotal
2. usaverage
3. dsaverage

But I can only get from "data". How do I access the other fields?

```
import json,urllib.request

data = urllib.request.urlopen("http://172.xx.xx.xx/stcs/bandwidthconsumption").read()
output = json.loads(data)

print(output['body']['data'][7])
```

```
{
  "body": {
    "data": [
      {
        "traffictotal": 0.28,
        "usaverage": 1.12,
        "dsaverage": 19.56,
        "ustotal": 0.01,
        "dstotal": 0.26
      }
    ],
    "msgs": [ "Successful" ]
  },
  "header": {
    "opCode": "1",
    "token": "",
    "state": "",
    "version": 1
  }
```

Comment: iterate the `data` list and then fetch the required keys

Comment: What `output ` is , can you show us the complete data?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to get the field values.

1. If the internal list has just one element as shown in the example, you could just get the first element and read the values matching the keys as:

```
print(output['body']['data'][0]['traffictotal'])
print(output['body']['data'][0]['usaverage'])
print(output['body']['data'][0]['dsaverage'])
```

Output:

```
0.28
1.12
19.56
```

2. If there are multiple elements in the list, you can iterate over them and prepare a dictionary/list depending on the data and get the value from that. Here is an example with creating a dictionary:

```
result = {key: value for elt in output['body']['data'] for key, value in elt.items() if key in ['traffictotal', 'usaverage', 'dsaverage']}
print(result)
print(result['traffictotal'])
print(result['usaverage'])
print(result['dsaverage'])
```

Output:

```
{'traffictotal': 0.28, 'usaverage': 1.12, 'dsaverage': 19.56}
0.28
1.12
19.56
```